# how to wait for a specified time until a command gives a desired output

Tags: python

I am writing a small python script to wait for a max of 1200 secs for devices to come up ,what is the best way to accomplish this?

command to run

```
device.exe list
```

Output when no devices attached:

```
List of devices attached
```

Output When devices attached

```
List of devices attached
device#1
device#2
device#3
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the `retrying` library:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying

You will likely need some combinations of `stop_max_delay` and `retry_on_result` keyword arguments with the `@retry` decorator.